# How can i upload multiple NSImages to Facebook using PhFacebook?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, macos, cocoa

I know how to upload simple text to facebook using PhFacebook, but i don't know how can i upload multiple nsimages to facebook using the same framework?

Can any1 explain me with example code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the code yourself, but try putting them in an `NSArray` and then looping through them, Uploading each time.

Comment: theres no way of uploading multiple at the same time with PhFacebook like we do on Mountain Lion?

Comment: Loop Through Them so You can upload them one at a time

Comment: by the way, sorry for answering this a bit late but how can i send the NSImage through PhFacebook? Do i need to convert to something else? because when i try to upload it does upload the image.